# How to set id for optional string for Dropdown in Strongly typed view..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My Strongly typed view consists of drop-down like below:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Text, ViewBag.Drop as SelectList,"Select a bus");
```

Above optional string is 'Select a Bus'.But I can't set id property as "0" for this.Remaining id values and text I fetch it from DB.I know I can put even optional string in DB table only.But I don't want like so.
So if I didn't select anything,and if I submit then 'null' value to Text property of model class in controller method which I don't want.I want's to return only "0" in this case.So My Controller is below.

```
public ActionResult Dropdown(DropdownCheck drpchk)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("some name");
        }

        return View("Dropdown");
    }
```

So how do I set id value to optional string..?

Comment: Why not add the additional value after you have retrieved the values from the DB?

Comment: @ChrisBint-How do I add it.?Thanks for interest..

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The whole point for the "Select a bus" `null` option is to post back `null` so that if its selected, `ModelState` will be invalid. By making it `value="0"` your ensuring that correct validation will not be done and your app may fail.

Comment: @StephenMuecke-At value="0" I wants to make post operation is invalid,instead of 'null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `SelectListItem` after retrieving from DB:

```
var buses = db.Buses.Select(t => new SelectListItem
{
     Text = t.SomeText,
     Value = t.SomeValue
}).ToList();

buses.Add(new SelectListItem
{
     Text = "--Select a Bus--",
     Value = "0",
     Selected = true
});

ViewBag.Drop = buses;
```

In your view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Text, ViewBag.Drop as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>);
```